# SQL - sum all the rows except above

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

| row | value | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 750 |
| 2 | 300 | 550 |
| 3 | 100 | 250 |
| 4 | 100 | 150 |
| 5 | 50 | 50 |

```
row 1 = row 1 + row 2 + row 3 + row 4 + row 5
row 2 = row 2 + row 3 + row 4 + row 5
...
row 5 = row 5
```

How could I achieve this sum column?

```
SELECT value from TableA;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a window function:

```
select id, val, sum(val) over (order by id desc) as [sum]
from t
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9874dfd/2)

Comment: Haven't seen you in a while +1, good answer.

Comment: Hi Tim, Happy new year!